# Interpreting Received Json in Android

Tags: php, android, json

I am here working on my app where m receiving a Json in android. Here is my php script which sends Json.

```
<?php
require_once 'DB_connect.php';
class populatelist{
    private $con;
    private $conn;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = new DB_connect();
        $this->conn = $this->con->connectWithRestaurant();
    }
    function selectallfields(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `restaurant_time` LIMIT 50";
        $result = $this->conn->query($query);
        if($result->num_rows >0)
        {
            while($record = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $response['resname'] = $record['Restaurant_name'];
                $response['restadd'] = $record['Address'];
                $response['resttime'] = $record['Waiting_time'];
                $response['images'] = $record['Logo'];
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
}


$function = new populatelist();
$function->selectallfields();

?>
```

And Here is my Android Code For Accepting this Json Request. This is responsible to send data to the custom adapter I have created.

```
 class Jsonfetch extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ListView>{

    @Override
    protected ListView doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://172.16.16.88/orderspot/populatelist.php");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();



            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String temp;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while((temp = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuilder.append(temp);
            }
            String JsonResponse = stringBuilder.toString();
            Log.i("JsonResposne",JsonResponse);
            try {
                JSONArray new_array =new JSONArray(JsonResponse);
                //int count;

                for(int i = 0, count = new_array.length();i<count;i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject  = new_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    list.add(new ListModel(jsonObject.getString("resname"),jsonObject.getString("restadd"),jsonObject.getString("resttime"),jsonObject.getString("images")));
                }
                final customAdapter myadapter = new customAdapter(getApplicationContext(),list);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            listView.setAdapter(myadapter);

                        }
                    });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listView;
    }
}
```

I exactly Dont know whats the problem with this code. But perhaps, I'm getting The Json in Invalid Format. 
And here is my Json Which I receive.

```
{"resname":"Sankalp","restadd":"Infocity","resttime":"South Indian","images":"25"}{"resname":"South Cafe","restadd":"Infocity","resttime":"South Indian","images":"20"}{"resname":"Uncle Sam","restadd":"Infocity","resttime":"Pizza","images":"15"}{"resname":"Dangee Dums","restadd":"Infocity","resttime":"Dessert","images":"10"}{"resname":"Fresh Roast","restadd":"Infocity","resttime":"Cafe","images":"5"}{"resname":"Cafe Natrani","restadd":"Infocity","resttime":"Cafe","images":"30"}{"resname":"Chocolate Room","restadd":"Infocity","resttime":"Chocolate","images":"0"}{"resname":"Subway","restadd":"Infocity","resttime":"Sandwich","images":"4"}{"resname":"Jai Bhawani","restadd":"Infocity","resttime":"Breakfast","images":"5"}{"resname":"Jai Bhawani","restadd":"Infocity","resttime":"Breakfast","images":"5"}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$response = array();

while($record = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $restaurant = array();
    $restaurant['resname'] = $record['Restaurant_name'];
    $restaurant['restadd'] = $record['Address'];
    $restaurant['resttime'] = $record['Waiting_time'];
    $restaurant['images'] = $record['Logo'];
    $response[] = $restaurant;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: It is invalid JSON with or without that line. That isn't the problem.

Comment: why is the accepted answer, a copy paste of mine - which had a variable renamed after I called it out.... people are good

Answer (score 2):

Your response from the server is in a `JSONObject` format. Not a `JSONArray`

Fix your php.

```
$response = array(); // JSONArray container

while($record = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Build each JSONObject with your desired key names
    $namedRecord = array();
    $namedRecord['resname'] = $record['Restaurant_name'];
    $namedRecord['restadd'] = $record['Address'];
    $namedRecord['resttime'] = $record['Waiting_time'];
    $namedRecord['images'] = $record['Logo'];

    // Insert each object into the array
    array_push($response, $namedRecord);
}

// Output the array of objects
echo json_encode($response);
```

You are trying to create a `JSONArray` of `JSONObjects` which should be formatted like this.

```
[{key:value,key1:value1,...},{anotherObjectKey:anotherObjectValue}]
```

Comment: m sorry at that time i had not initialize the array so it showed null. But now after Initializing,  it shows "[]". and to add to your answer, shouldn't $response be the first Parameter ?

Comment: First parameter of array_push is the destination. Second is the source. Try initializing both arrays as in my edit. That might fix it (I'm a php noob) but I have exactly what you are doing in production code that works fine.

Comment: @Milind Delete the body of your if statement, and copy paste my block of code in. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Print your JSON response in the Log and validate it on..

http://jsonlint.com/

Your response is not a valid JSON, it contains many JSONObjects which should be comma separates which they are not, and all of them should be contained inside an JSONArray. Please format it properly.

Check this link on how to build JSONArray in php,

http://alvinalexander.com/php/php-json_encode-convert-array-to-json-example

Your response should be as,

```
"rstaurants" :[
{
"resname": "Sankalp",
"restadd": "Infocity",
"resttime": "South Indian",
"images": "25"
},
{
"resname": "South Cafe",
"restadd": "Infocity",
"resttime": "South Indian",
"images": "20"
},
{
"resname": "Uncle Sam",
"restadd": "Infocity",
"resttime": "Pizza",
"images": "15"
},
{
"resname": "Dangee Dums",
"restadd": "Infocity",
"resttime": "Dessert",
"images": "10"
},
{
"resname": "Fresh Roast",
"restadd": "Infocity",
"resttime": "Cafe",
"images": "5"
}
]
```

Currently it is,

```
{
"resname": "Sankalp",
"restadd": "Infocity",
"resttime": "South Indian",
"images": "25"
}
{
"resname": "South Cafe",
"restadd": "Infocity",
"resttime": "South Indian",
"images": "20"
}
{
"resname": "Uncle Sam",
"restadd": "Infocity",
"resttime": "Pizza",
"images": "15"
}
{
"resname": "Dangee Dums",
"restadd": "Infocity",
"resttime": "Dessert",
"images": "10"
}
{
"resname": "Fresh Roast",
"restadd": "Infocity",
"resttime": "Cafe",
"images": "5"
}
```

Let me know if it works for you...
And do mark it as answer so that it would be useful to others...

Comment: Can u please Guide me ?

Comment: @Milind by copy pasting my answer ;P